# Do you have to use Size Classes if you are developing for iPhone only?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I understand the role of auto-layout but if I am developing for iPhone devices only, should I still use size classes? From my understanding, size classes are extremely useful if I am developing for iPad as well, in my case I am not. Would the more sensible option be to use size classes but just use COMPACT WIDTH | REGULAR HEIGHT ?? Or should I not use size classes and just build my app using auto-layout?

Comment: Actually size classes are much _more_ important for iPhone than for iPad, because they tell you your orientation. When the app interface rotates, the size classes change - that's not true on the iPad, only on the iPhone.

Comment: "Or should I not use size classes and just build my app using auto-layout?" It isn't an either/or thing. You use both.

Comment: Also, the 5.5" iPhone 6 Plus is very different than the smaller iPhones and size classes help you deal with that one as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two situations where size classes are useful in the iPhone development:

- If you want to support landscape and portrait and want to have different constraints in different orientations and even hiding/showing different vies.
- If you want to do a **SPECIFIC** layout for iPhone 6+ in **LANDSCAPE**

If you don't want these two conditions, you can ignore size classes them or disabling them.

For more information on the differentiation you can have with the current [devices check out this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html).

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question perfectly as my app will be iPhone only and it will support portrait orientation only.

Comment: @JoseCalles if the answer is perfect please consider accept it (the check mark in the answer) so other users can easily see that this answer solves your question,

Answer (score 1):

The problem with iphone is that there 4 sizes of iphone in the market right now.

- Iphone 6 Iphone 6 Plus Iphone 5 Iphone 4

Using **COMPACT WIDTH | REGULAR HEIGHT** will limit your option when you rotate your device

iphone 6 iphone 5 and iphone 4 when rotated ->
 **COMPACT WIDTH | COMPACT HEIGHT**

Therefore I would rather recommend you to code in **ANY WIDTH|ANYHEIGHT** so it is more compatible to any UI SIZE

*note size classes is useful when implementing extra buttons in different UI
ie. suppose you create an calculator app, in an iPad it can fit extra button while in iphone you can't . so you use size classes to make sure you share the same codebase

source CS193p, stanford IOS 8 course